# wss 3.0 missing sharepoint list attachments contents

Tags: attachments, third-party-software, wss

I encountered with one problem where the wss 3.0 site lists attachments contents are missing .Attachments appear in the list but when i click on them, contents inside the attachments are not there. This is happening for custom solution i just deployed from third party provider. All other attachments works except for the new custom list created from custom solution. Is there anything i can do as a site admin to make necessary changes, or is it issue of the custom solution.

Thank You

Comment: Have you contacted the third party provider for support?

Comment: Yes i am trying to, but they are kinda trying to blame on my server settings. I told them back in responce if there was any problems in my server it wouldnt work for other lists either. Now waiting for there response......

Comment: That's not very helpful of them, who are they...? Try to narrow down the issue. Try to reproduce it on another farm (if you have one), another web application, another site collection, another web site and finally on another list.

Comment: what company is it, and what does the solution do (other than create a poorly configured list)?

Comment: Thank You guys its workin now they must have messed up in <asp:fileupload> to grab the right file and upload it into the custom list. He used FileStream fStream = File.OpenRead(postFile.FileName)   instead of Stream MyStream_Marks = postFile.InputStream;

Comment: @octopus please post that as the answer and then mark your question off as answered.